# decoding a text string to use in a join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-01722

I'm trying to extract the number from a text string and join it to another table.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT sect.id, 
       sect.section_number, 
       sect.expression, 
       p.abbreviation
  FROM sections sect
  JOIN period p ON SUBSTR(sect.expression, 1, (INSTR(sect.expression,'(')-1)) = p.period_number 
               AND p.schoolid = 73253 
               AND p.year_id = 20
  JOIN courses c ON sect.course_number = c.course_number
 WHERE sect.schoolid = 73253 
   AND sect.termid >= 2000
```

I read some other threads and figured out how to strip out the number (which always comes before the left parenthesis).  The problem is that this only accounts for two of the three styles of data that live in the sect.expression column-

```
9(A) - check  
10(A) - check
```

but not

```
5-6(A)
```

5-6(A) would kick back an Oracle 01722 invalid number error.
Is there a way I could modify the substr... line so that for the 5-6(A) data type it would grab the first number (the 5) and join off of that?

It's worth mentioning that I only have read rights to this table so any solution that depends on creating some kind of helper table/column won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Too bad with read only... They should consider adding a corresponding "period_number" column in table sections, with the same data type as in table period. The optimizer cannot use the gathered statistics efficiently on SUBSTR(col,x,x) to calculate join selectivity. This is only a problem if the erronous calculation results in a different execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE

1) If you want to extract only numbers:

```
JOIN period p ON REGEXP_REPLACE(sect.expression, '[^0-9]', '') = p.period_number
```

2) If you want to match with the digits in the start of the string and ignore the ones that appear later:

```
JOIN period p ON REGEXP_REPLACE(sect.expression, '^(\d+)(.*)', '\1')
```

Comment: It would yeild 56. Updated the post to extract the starting digits only.

Comment: The change perfectly handles all three data types - including the 5-6(A) example.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Being [Oracle 10g, you could use a regex](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) instead:

```
JOIN period p ON REGEXP_SUBSTR(sect.expression, '^\d+', 1, 1) = p.period_number
```

Admittedly, the regex I provided needs work - it will get the first number at the start of the string.  If you need a more complicated regex, I recommend this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: thanks!  for 10(A) would it kick back 1 or 10?  that's the other main case that needs to be accounted for - 2 digit numbers that occur before **either** a '(' or a '-'

Comment: @Andrew: `\d+` will match a numeric value of any length; the `^` ensures that the string must start with a numeric value.  Like my last statement reads, you should really read up on & heavily test if you're going to look at using regex.